# Office Add-in buttons not calling functions

Tags: office-js

I've been working on this project, a simple Table of Contents add-in for Excel. I can't seem to get my buttons to fire. I'm able to debug and see my taskpane, but clicking my buttons do nothing.

There are 2 buttons: create and remove. My js file is [here](https://github.com/DataAutoPros/Excel-Web-Table-of-Contents/blob/master/Excel%20Web%20Table%20of%20ContentsWeb/Home.js).

EDIT

Using ScriptLab, the below code is what I *successfully* tested. However, when I tried to port it back to VS the buttons do nothing when clicked.

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {

    var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("items/name");
    var sheetName = 'Table of Contents';
    await context.sync();

    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {

        var toc = sheets.items.find(ws => ws.name == sheetName);
        if (!toc) {
          toc = sheets.add(sheetName);
          context.sync();
        } else {
          toc.getUsedRange().clear();
        }
        toc.load("name, position");
        context.sync();

        var values = [];
        var count = 0;
        sheets.items.forEach((ws) => {
          if (ws.name !== sheetName) {
            values.push([(count + 1), "=HYPERLINK(\"#\"&\"'\" & \"" + ws.name + "\" & \"'!A1\",\"" + ws.name + "\")"]);
            count++;
          }
        })

        toc.position = 0;
        toc.activate();
        toc.getRange("A:A").format.columnWidth = 2;
        toc.getRange("B:B").format.columnWidth = 20;
        toc.getRange("C:C").format.columnWidth = 200;
        toc.getRange("C:C").format.wrapText = true;
        toc.getRange("1:1").format.rowHeight = 5;
        toc.getRange("3:3").format.rowHeight = 5;
        toc.getRange("B2").values = [["Table of Contents"]];
        toc.getRange("B2").format.font.size = 18;
        toc.getRange("B2").format.font.bold = true;

        if (values.length === 0) {
          console.log('error 1');
          return context.sync();
        }

        var dataRangeAddress = `B4:C${3 + (count || 1)}`;
        var dataRange = toc.getRange(dataRangeAddress);
        context.sync();
        dataRange.values = values;
        toc.calculate(false);

        return context.sync();
      });

    await context.sync();
  });
};

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is that you have a `for ... in` loop running over `sheets.items`:

```
for (i in sheets.items)
```

But [WorksheetCollection.items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#items) is an array. It is considered a bad practice to use a `for ... in` loop over an array. (See [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).) Aside from that, doing something non-standard like that makes it harder for others to reason about your code.

More importantly, you need to get more information about what is going wrong. Please download the [ScriptLab tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab). You can use it to test your methods and it has a nice console that will report errors to you.

UPDATE: I also see that your `removeTableOfContents` function tests the truth of `!sheet`, but no variable named `sheet` is declared in the file, so `!sheet` will always resolve as truthy.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it was an object to iterate. I'm loosely understanding the differences there.

Thank you for the links. I tried ScriptLab but got an error. Not sure how to post the code I used, there is a limit to these comments. Very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, the original sheet loop I got was from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets.

Comment: Good catch. I'll have that loop fixed.

Comment: Updated the code in the post. Got it working in ScriptLab, still not working in VS project. Perhaps it's the callbacks?

Comment: Your handler assignments put double quotation marks around the handler name like this `$('#tosCreate').click("createTableOfContents")`. Remove the double quotation marks.

Comment: Ah, right. I had tested both ways as I wasn't sure which was proper. Taking them out has no change. I tried removing the 'async' in the Excel.run construct, as that's how the examples show but it didn't change anything. Buttons still aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was working from a template and adjusting it. This was created in an earlier version of VS (2015) before upgrading to 2019. As such, I found slight differences in naming conventions.

This particular issue was related to the Office.initialize function in the 'element' and 'messageBanner' variables. Adjusting this code let the buttons work a treat. I suspect if I had not created the original project in an earlier version, it probably would've worked just fine.

Original/offending code:

```
    var element = document.querySelector('.ms-MessageBanner');
    messageBanner = new fabric.MessageBanner(element);
```

Adjusted/working code:

```
    var element = document.querySelector('.MessageBanner');
    messageBanner = new components.MessageBanner(element);
```